# Why does chromium throw a Sandbox_lix error?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

When I run chromium in ubuntu terminal I get

```
Gtk-Message: 16:08:14.534: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[2674:2674:0209/160818.019361:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[2701:1:0209/160822.146414:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[2701:1:0209/160822.146850:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
```

If instead I try chromium-browser

```
Gtk-Message: 16:08:14.534: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[2674:2674:0209/160818.019361:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[2701:1:0209/160822.146414:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
[2701:1:0209/160822.146850:ERROR:child_process_sandbox_support_impl_linux.cc(79)] FontService unique font name matching request did not receive a response.
```

I tried 
`sudo apt install canberra-gtk-module` and got an unable to locate package error and successfully used 
`sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module`

My concern is that the errors refer to Sandbox. Which makes me think the errors mean that the browser won't be sandboxed properly which is a safety concern. so how do I fix this error?